# Acessing session data to query DB to pull other data

Tags: php, session-variables

So when a user logs into my site, I pull the user ID from the users table and save it in the session. THis works i've tested it by using

```
echo "test" . $_SESSION['UserID'];
```

this displays the current user ID
now how do I use $_SESSION['UserID'] in a mysql query to get a number from a different table which has user ID as a foreign key?

Apologies if this seems stupid, first time dealing with sessions

Comment: Find a way to pass a variable to your SQL query, then assign userID to that variable..

Answer (score 0):

You can directly hold the value of `$_SESSION['UserID']` into a variable and use it like a normal PHP constructs.

Perhaps one of the way:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['UserID'])) {
    $userId = $_SESSION['UserID'];
    $sql= 'select * from user_addresses where UserID = '.$userId;
}
```

Comment: how do I get that to pull a different column in the same table, user id is being passed from session data fine with that

Comment: it's called tokens and has tokenID as primary, UserID as foreign then tokenamount as an int

Comment: `mysql_query('Select * from tokens where UserID = '.$userId);`

Comment: Is that not just the same as the previous answer?

Comment: well I tried this, you might be able to work out what i'm trying to do

Comment: $userId = $_SESSION['UserID'];
 
    $sql = mysql_query('Select * from tokens where UserID =     '.$userId);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)): //fetching the row from database

   $tokenamount = $row['TokenAmount']; //the id column in your table
   $_SESSION['TokenAmount'] = $tokenamount; //the id is now saved in session for future use

    endwhile;

    echo "Current Amount:" .$_SESSION['TokenAmount'];